# useless pin_ptr while copying array

Tags: arrays, c++-cli, pin-ptr

I have some legacy code, which copy a native array into a managed one:

```
float* nativeValues = new float[NumberOfSamples];
array<double>^ managedValues = gcnew array<double>(NumberOfSamples);

pin_ptr<double> pinnedValues = &managedValues[0];
for (int i = 0; i < managedValues->Length; i++)
{
    nativeValues[i] = (float) pinnedValues[i];
}
```

I can't refactor it with `Runtime::InteropServices::Marshal::Copy` because the original array is double and the target one is float.

My problem is I don't get why the pin_ptr. I dont' think is needed but its a critical piece of code and I'd like to be sure before removing it.

Do you think is it safe to remove it?

Comment: I understand the pinning would be needed if I was accessing the managed array via pointer arithmetics. But it is just using the indexer, so it should really not important if the GC kicks in and move stuff around

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pin_ptr would be needed if you were going to pass the pin_ptr *directly* to an unmanaged API as a `double*`.

```
void SomeUnmanagedAPI(double* data, int length);

// Example of where pin_ptr would be needed.
pin_ptr<double> pinnedValues = &managedValues[0];
SomeUnmanagedAPI(pinnedValues, managedValues->Length);
```

For either the manual copy, or the Marshal::Copy, it's not needed. Go ahead and remove it, and just iterate over managedValues.